# extracting date from a string when there are extra values behind the date value

Tags: regex, oracle, date

I get data from clients with date values that sometimes includes extra digits.  Here are a few examples: 
2/13/201733246

2/15/20179714

3/7/201712718

These values are loaded into a staging table as a string, but I need to extract the date portion and load that into a final destination table as a date.

I have tried using regex, and can select the pattern for the date, but am stuck from there.  How can I choose the values that are not part of the date and get rid of them?  Can I do this with oracle regexp?

I have also tried to add a leading 0 to the month and date portions, and can identify when it is just the one digit, but how do I add the 0 along with the original number?

If I use substr, that works if both month and date are 2 digit but fails when either one is a single digit.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: The question is if you have a pattern you can rely on. For example, do you always have '/' to separate day, month year? Is always the year written in four digits?

Comment: Yes, the dates are always MM/DD/YYYY.  The inconsistent part is the bits that follow the year.  That said, the MM/DD portion may be either 1 digit or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way:

```
with inputData(str) as (
    select '2/13/201733246' from dual union all
    select '2/15/20179714' from dual union all
    select '3/7/201712718' from dual
)
select str, regexp_substr(str, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}')
from inputData
```

This can be re-written in different, more compact, ways, but I believe this is easy to read.

The regexp looks twice for a sequence of one or two digits (`[0-9]{1,2}`) followed by a `/`, then for a sequence of exactly 4 digits `([0-9]{4})` for the year.

Another way, without using regexp, could be the following:

```
substr(str, 1, instr(str, '/', 1, 2) +4 )
```

This looks for the 2nd occurrence of a `/` and gives the substring from the first character up to the second `/` plus 4 characters for the year.

The result:

```
SQL> with inputData(str) as (
  2      select '2/13/201733246' from dual union all
  3      select '2/15/20179714' from dual union all
  4      select '3/7/201712718' from dual
  5  )
  6  select str,
  7         regexp_substr(str, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}') str1,
  8         substr(str, 1, instr(str, '/', 1, 2) +4 ) str2
  9  from inputData;

STR                  STR1       STR2
-------------------- ---------- ----------
2/13/201733246       2/13/2017  2/13/2017
2/15/20179714        2/15/2017  2/15/2017
3/7/201712718        3/7/2017   3/7/2017
```

No matter the way you decide to use, if you need to get the result in `DATE` format, you have to use a `to_date` to convert the string result shown above.

For example,
`regexp_substr(str, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}')`
should become
`to_date(regexp_substr(str, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: That is perfect!!  I used the regexp you provided and not only did it worked I learned something to boot.  Thank you!

Comment: Since question is how to extract a DATE you should surround the expression also by TO_DATE, i.e `TO_DATE(regexp_substr(str, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')` in order to get a `DATE` as result.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the TO_DATE part.  I failed to completely show what I had done by that omission but maybe it will help someone else looking to accomplish this.